# Understanding what php daemons are

Tags: php, daemon, definition

I just Google "What is a php daemon" but I only recieved result on how to create php daemon.
Please can someone clearly explain to me the concept behind it?
It will help me for my test. Thank in advance...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**php daemons :** Asynchronous server-side framework for Web and network applications implemented in PHP using libevent. phpDaemon can handle thousands of simultaneous connections

**For Tutorial:**

> http://collaboradev.com/2011/03/31/php-daemons-tutorial/
>
> http://www.xarg.org/2016/07/how-to-write-a-php-daemon/

Comment: This is what i saw on https://daemon.io/ but it can't help me to fully understand what php daemons are. I said I am preparing for an exam, so I need more details like a tutorial please.

Comment: http://collaboradev.com/2011/03/31/php-daemons-tutorial/

Comment: http://www.xarg.org/2016/07/how-to-write-a-php-daemon/